# PerspectiveTranform JavaFX code fails to compile? add(Node) error

Tags: java

I've been working on a project involving PerspectiveTransform in the JavaFX library (on Java, of course), but my IDE keeps giving me this error at the .add part:

```
The method add(Node) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (Rectangle)
```

Below is the code I'm using:

```
    PerspectiveTransform pt = new PerspectiveTransform(20,0,400,0,0,600,300,600);
    Group gr = new Group();
    gr.setEffect(pt);
    gr.setCache(true);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300,250);
    gr.getChildren().add(rect);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right, what could be the issue here? I'm using Eclipse is that means anything, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: You are probably importing `java.awt.Rectangle` rather than JavaFX's [`javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html).

Comment: Yup, this was the problem! Thanks