# Add a Rectangle to root in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

i try to create some shapes of javafx library..

So, in the 'start' method, when i create a new circle and i add it to the root, i don't have any problem :

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Circle cercle = new Circle();
        cercle.setCenterX(300);
        cercle.setCenterY(200);
        cercle.setRadius(100);
        cercle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        cercle.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        cercle.setStrokeWidth(5);

        root.getChildren().add(cercle);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

but, when i try to do this with a rectangle, the compiler doesn't accept, and draw a red line under the 'add' method

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.setX(300);
        rectangle.setY(200);
        rectangle.setWidth(300);
        rectangle.setHeight(200);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.DARKGREEN);
        rectangle.setStrokeWidth(5);
        rectangle.setArcHeight(30);
        rectangle.setArcWidth(30);

        root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

The compiler say :

> The method add(Node) in the type List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Rectangle)

I see this in other programs, it work normally.

Note: I use eclipse luna and jdk 8

Comment: You talk about Triangle, but have Rectangle in code. Anyway: What did you import?

[You are probably importing java.awt.Rectangle rather than JavaFX's javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243203/perspectivetranform-javafx-code-fails-to-compile-addnode-error)

Comment: sorry i correct it

Comment: i don't think it's about import, because the declaration of rectangle work normally.. but adding this rectangle to root fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
```

instead of

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

Comment: i have this import : com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle ... import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle doesn't work !

Comment: Ah ok ! it doesn't work because the two imports must not be together.. so i remove com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle and i put javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle ... thank you :-)

Comment: That's why I wrote "instead of". Didn't know you had "geom.Rectangle", I assumed you had awt.Rectangle. Anyway, general explanation:

Whenever you type "Rectangle" the compiler and eclipse need to know which you want. Sadly, there are multiple classes of Rectangle with the same name. That's also producing the confusing error message. It would be clear if it said: "not applicable for arguments (geom.Rectangle)". But since they have namespaces you can specify which you want. I assume you imported Rectangle using Eclipse tooltip, which suggested multiple, where you chose the first one.

Answer (score 3):

`com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle` is a JDK internal class and does NOT extend the `Node` class but you should not be using internal classes anyway. Remove this internal import and instead replace with:

`import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle`